# is it possible to place a debug point on a typescript file in visual code editor?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is it possible to place a debug point on a typescript file in visual code editor? So when we ng serve, it will pop chrome-dev tools and boom, it pause the execution right on the corresponding like as if you did command+p, search for that file, find that line and manually mark it by hand.

I'm asking this but I'm almost certain that we are not there yet. 
But let me ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. Although I didn't understand what are you trying to say in the description. You can put debug pointer in the .ts file.

If you need help, Go Here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

This one has a complete guide.